# AVD located in custom path cannot be use to run an app (in Windows 10)

Tags: android, android-studio

Due to a non-ASCII character in my user name, the default path for any AVD includes a non-ASCII character in its path and when I try to run an app over these AVDs, the AVD simply doesn't work.

To correct this issue I've set `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` environment variable to an ASCII folder. Now when I run the app over the AVDs, the AVD opens up correctly, however, Android Studio hangs by saying...

> Waiting for target device to come online.

How can I make the run the apps over these AVDs?

*NOTE: I'm using Windows 10 so unless I make a complete clean install it doesn't seem to be a way to change my #HOME folder which contains the non-ASCII characters.*

*NOTE: I can run apps via an actual connected device perfectly. So there is nothing wrong with the Android Studio save for AVD-related problems.*

Comment: Looks like a bug in Android Studio (by which I mean, everything AS manages, including the emulator). I'd make sure I search for and possibly report it here: https://developer.android.com/studio/report-bugs.html

Comment: The only workaround I can think of is to reinstall the AS stuff to somewhere not in AppData.